# Oracle TO_DATE() function gives undesired output

Tags: oracle, date

I have a DATE column with Oracle timestamp datatype in database

It stores values as such:

```
06-SEP-13 05.22.23.000000000 PM
```

I try to do this `TO_CHAR(DATE, 'dd-MM-yyyy')` and I get this: `06-09-2013`.

then I try to convert the output to date using `TO_DATE`,

```
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(DATE, 'dd-MM-yyyy'), 'dd-MM-yyyy')
```

but I get this: `06-SEP-13`.

I am expecting it to be in this format `06-09-2013`.

Why is this happening?

Help is much appreciated..

Comment: Why are you converting a `date` to a `varchar` and then back to a `date`? That doesn't make any sense. Your first `to_char()` already creates the expected result.

Comment: Yes your right.. anyways like @Alex Poole says it takes the default `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` no matter how I try to convert to a different date format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`to_date()` doesn't give the date any format; dates and timestamps have an internal representation and don't have any meaningful/useful format until they are displayed somewhere. You're converting your timestamp into a string and then back into a date, which you coild also do with

```
cast(trunc(your_timestamp) as date)
```

where the [`trunc` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/functions220.htm) removes the time portion, and [the `cast` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/functions023.htm) converts the result from timestamp to date.

When your query displays that date, however you construct it, your client decides what format to use. If you don't explicitly specify a format with `to_char()` then your client will use a default, usually `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`. You can change that for each session, but you should not rely on implicit settings that might be different when someone else runs the code, so always use `to_char` for display.

Comment: The trunc function helped.. I will try to change the date format through my client code itself. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

What tool are you using? I am sure it's NLS date format session setting of it.

Comment: I am using Oracle SQL Developer. You mean to say that I have to change the date format in NLS settings of the tool. But can't it be done without changing settings?

Comment: Yes. Edit preference, under database find NLS. Then look for date.

Comment: As you said it is regarding the NLS date format but I don't want to mess up with the NLS settings so will rather go with @Alex answer. Thank you.